# How to include two figures horizontally in Jupyter Notebook using LaTeX, ready to export to PDF?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, latex, pandoc, nbconvert

I want to include two figures as shown [here](https://shantoroy.com/latex/add-subfig-in-latex/).

I tried to use the **Markdown syntax**, however, when exporting to PDF, the two images go out of bounds of the page. Pandoc can't convert HTML to LaTeX and vice versa, so **including the figures in HTML also isn't an option**.

Finally, using [(some) LaTeX environments for Jupyter notebook](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/latex_envs/README.html) I was able to include LaTeX code into Markdown cells so that it shows in the notebook itself. I have two issues now however. This is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  % include first image
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{attachments/alpha-games.jpg}  
  \caption{AlphaZero games}
  \label{fig:games}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  % include second image
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{attachments/fb-robots.jpg}  
  \caption{Robots}
  \label{fig:robots}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Uses of Reinforcement learning in real life.}
\label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}
```

This is the output in Jupyter Notebook:

[image: Jupyter Notebook output]

Only one image is showing, the other is not. Also, the figure caption is not centered.

That's the other issue, the **figure captions are not centered under the image**, but aligned to the left. Even under simple figures (not subfigures).

**So what I need is for the figures to show correctly in both Jupyter Notebook and also after converting the notebook to PDF via LaTeX.**

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Is it acceptable to show the figures using IPython's `display` function or does it have to be Markdown/LaTeX in the notebook?

Comment: Hello @butterwagon, it has had to be Markdown/LaTeX. I want to make the notebook into an academic paper basically. I've switched to Jupyter Book however, in which the captions show up correctly.